# How can I check if window forward is enabled through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have to do one functionality if the user lands one page and going to another page and comes back to the same page. I want do it by checking the forward button enabled or not?
Can any one help me on this.

Do I have any other way to check this?

Comment: what do you mean "window forward is enabled"? Do you mean forward is available??

Comment: It's hard to guess what you are actually looking for.

Comment: but there should be a way to find that right?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple one line answer is NO, You cant check.**

> **Security**

As the security concern, you cant get history list *(of current tab browsing)*, Just you will get is total history count. But not the index of current page in that list.

> **History API**

The history API has `window.history.forward()` method which allows you to move forward, If next page is not available it will do nothing. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) is reference.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can use `navigation.canGoForward` Chrome >= 102 [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_API)